# How to override font-size (em) in this condition?

Tags: css, xhtml

I don't want to edit `p {font-size:1.3em; padding-bottom:15px;}` and can't add page specific external css files.

only for one page of site I want to remove font size from p `{font-size:1.3em; padding-bottom:15px;}` and want to add in this

```
#mainIntro {font-size:1.3em;}
```

How to make this possible?

The questions is how to neutralize the font size in `#mainIntro p {....}`

if i keep

`#mainIntro {font-size:1.3em;}` then i will get double size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the cascade, you can't just remove the font-size:1.3em specification.

Try this:

```
#mainIntro {font-size:1.3em;}
#mainIntro p { 100%; }
```

This will set the font size for that div to 1.3em, and then override the existing font size for #mainIntro p to 100% of it's current size; thus preventing the double font-size.

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose html body code on this particular page with

```
<div class="mySpecialPage"> 

... [page's html code]
<div />
```

and then add statement to css file using selectors

Comment: no need to enclose it in a special div, just give the body tag an id

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the head after the external stylesheet. Depending on styling you might need to add !important to the p declaration.

```
<style>
p {font-size:1em}
#mainIntro {font-size:1.3em;}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a jQuery script to check for the page and modify the style on the fly.

I am not a master in jQuery and so not writing the script for you.